# Typewriter - Public variables instead of getter setter methods from C# to Typescript

Tags: c#, typescript, typewriter

I have following Typescript Template. *.tst

```
module App { $Classes(*Model)[
    export class $Name { $Properties[
        public $name: $Type;]
    }]
}
```

It has generated Model as expected for following using typewriter. (For Getter Setter)

```
public class CustomerModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ICollection<OrderModel> Orders { get; set; }
    }
```

But I could not find any documentation or don't know if it is possible for following to generate typescript file. (For Public Variables.)

```
public class CustomerModel
        {
            public int Id;
            public string Name;
            public ICollection<OrderModel> Orders;
        }
```

So how can I generate typescript for public variable?

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. I got things worked through intellisense. tst file should look like below.

```
module App { $Classes(*Model)[
    export class $Name { $Fields[
        public $name: $Type;]
    }]
}
```